# Does Islam may accept that Allah and his angels are extraterrestrial beings?

Tags: allah, malaikah

Does Islam may accept one day that Allah and his angels are extraterrestrial beings?
Aliens could create a man.

The story about Adam and Eve sounds like Allah/God is very similar to us.

We also can fly to other planet one day and create beings to leave there. I am wondering what we will tell them in that case. I think we will call them Adam and Eve.

There is theory that it is possible to create even universe with Big Bang in thing like Large Hadron Collider.

Comment: This question is all over the place. Can you please rewrite it and make it concentrate on one question only?

Comment: It is single question. Question is in subject. Other lines are not necessary but tell why I ask it. I am wondering about theological things like `can god create another god`, `can god create a stone so heavy that he cannot move it`

Answer (score 1):

You have a false notion of what Allah is, in Islam.

Allah is the only god, so by definition there is no other god than him and so the situation you describe is impossible and is illogical.

And Allah is capable of everything, so the situation you described is impossible.

Comment: Ok. Could `Houri` in paradise be alien women on other planet ?